# How can I execute python anaconda with atom 1.0

Tags: atom-editor

I've installed atom 1.0 and I want to execute my python 3.4 from Anaconda 3. All errors are because atom not detect my anaconda packages. I don't find the file to change the settings for python to anaconda python.

Answer (score 10):

You can add the path to the Anaconda python to the start of your path in your init.coffee file. In the "Atom" menu, select "Open Your Init Script". Or, use Command-shift-P to open the fuzzy finder and type something along the lines of "Open Your Init Script":

[image]
then, add something like:

```
 process.env.PATH = ['/Users/dan/anaconda/bin/', process.env.PATH].join(':')
```

to the end of init.coffee. Of course, you need to replace `/Users/dan/anaconda/bin` with the path to your `anaconda/bin` directory. If you don't already know this, try typing `which python` on the command line.

Once you've added the line, save init.coffee and restart Atom.

Answer (score 5):

Try starting atom from terminal. Otherwise it does not load the $PATH variable defined by anaconda in ~/.bash_profile

Comment: this is really sad :-/

Comment: This is especially true for Windows. Could'nt find any other way to make Atom work with Anaconda, other than starting Atom from the Anaconda promt.